# Table of contents: title added as section

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, apa6

I'm using `apa6` with TeX Live 2012 and would like to use the command `\maketitle`. However, whenever I do, the title of my document always appears above my table of contents, and it is even listed as a section in my table of contents. Here we go:

```
\documentclass[man,a4paper]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\title{Title}
\shorttitle{shorttitle}
\author{Name}
\abstract{abstract text here}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\include{text}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked just fine:    \documentclass[man,a4paper,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}

Answer (score 6):

You can use the option `donotrepeattitle` to suppress this section.